# Python WAV "TypeError: data type not understood" error

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, wav

I've had a problem reading a .wav file using Python. I want to read the amplitude and sampling rate of the file.

I tried reading the file using the following code:

```
import os
folder = os.getcwd() + '\\WAV'
file_name = 'Guitar.ff.sul_E.C5Bb5'
path = folder + '\\' + file_name + '.wav'
rate,data=read(path)
```

Before the above code, I imported the `read` function from the `scipy` library as follows:

> from scipy.io.wavfile import read,write

And from `numpy` I imported:

> from numpy import linspace,sin,pi,int16

I received the error "TypeError: data type not understood".

The code worked perfectly for a different .wav file, and I'd like to know how (if it's possible) I can change the code to read this one, or if I must change the .wav file before I can read it.

Below are the properties of the files:

1. File: Guitar.ff.sul_E.C5Bb5.wav

   - Size: 38.87 MB
   - Length: 1 minute 10 seconds
   - Sample Rate: 96 KHz
   - Sample Size: 24 bit
   - Bit Rate: 4,608 kbps
   - Channels: *tried 1 and 2*
2. File: 440hzAtone.wav

   - Size: 173 KB
   - Length : 2 seconds
   - Sample Rate: 44.1 KHz
   - Sample Size: 16 bit
   - Bit Rate: 705 kbps
   - Channels: 1

The first file didn't work and the second file did.

I got the exact same error for 1 and 2 channels.

Changing the file name so that it doesn't have dots doesn't matter. It seems to reach the file either way but not be able to read it.

**Edit:**

After changing the bit depth from 24 to 16 the problem is gone. Thank you Warren Weckesser for the comment.

Comment: If you could also provide us the properties of the files that did work, we might be able to spot something. Also a more complete code could improve your chances of getting a decent answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, scipy's wavfile reader can't read 24 bit files: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/1930

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser You should add that as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, scipy's wavfile reader can't read 24 bit files: [scipy issue 1930 on github](http://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/1930)

Check out https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wavio or get the source at https://github.com/WarrenWeckesser/wavio